# Push Notification mechanism between a server and a client app

Tags: c#, wcf, push-notification

I am developping a desktop application using C#, which communicates with a server over a WCF Web Service. It is supposed to be a kind of synchronization application. Meaning that when I make some changes on client app I should immediately update the server too(this is easy using service calls), but also this mechanism should be provided vice versa, a change on server must immediately be applied on several clients. I know I can make polling to my server but this doesn't look neat to me, and also I've heard of duplex services, but I'm not sure if I can use it to implement this mechanism.

I am asking for some suggestions over this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check http://signalr.net/ use browser control its meet your requirement ...hope this help you...

Comment: WCF duplex services will fit your needs. Take a look here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/491844/A-Beginners-Guide-to-Duplex-WCF

Comment: are you sure signalr.net meets my requirements? Because I am writing a desktop application, but this looks like only working on web? Am I wrong?

Comment: Here is a stackoverflow article describing the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693050/implementing-observer-pattern-using-wcf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to implement a publish and subscribe design. In WCF you could use net-tcp protocol to connect in duplex clients and server.

You could download a quite good implementation on http://www.idesign.net/Downloads/GetDownload/2032

And you will find a good article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx).

Regards

Answer (score 2):

tolga,
you can use winforms with signalR, server side can be asp.net or a standalone windows application..

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll check that signalR thing. I've been hearing that, but I thought it only works with web applications, if it is supported in winforms too, it really could be an alternative to the duplex services.

Answer (score 2):

[PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp) :A server-side library for sending Push Notifications to clients (the clients are basically mobile devices - but can be custom as well)!
You google to get some tutorial on PushSharp use as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var webAddr = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization:key=YOUR_SERVER_KEY");
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{\"to\": \"/topics/news\",\"notification\": {\"body\": \"New news added in application!\",\"title\":\"" + Your_Notif_Title+ "\",}}";
            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```